# Adding an image in Java

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am getting an error: `Image is abstract; cannot be instantiated` in line 39. In line 45, the error `cannot find symbol`.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that you *should* be able to instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: gun1 is defined in a different context, it will not be accessible in the drawGun() method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all the previous answers didnt mention that `java.awt.Image` is actually an abstract class that cannot be instantiated, well i had to interfere!
the is the best way to create an Image.

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

oh yah not to mention that `gun1` object isnt defined in `drawGun(Graphics2D g)` method...

Comment: This is the method that I used for it. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class that extends Image such as BufferedImage . This has to do with basic OOP.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I updated it, you were looking at old version

Answer (score 0):

To load an `Image`, you can use java.awt.Toolkit.getImage(...), or (often the better option) javax.imageio.ImageIO's `read` methods

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate a local variable out of it method.
You need to put "gun1" before the constructor, and then use "gun1 = gun.getImage()" at the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass gun1 as a parameter to your drawGun method, or declare gun1 as a member variable.

Image is an abstract class, it cannot be instanced. You can read more about abstract class here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

To get an instance of Image you can use a class that will take care of that for you like ImageIO or something like this

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon((Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(url)));
```

Bonus using ImageIcon will let you draw animated gif.